# StreamWriter not writing to file when called from task Scheduler C#

Tags: c#, windows, scheduled-tasks, streamwriter

I have the following function, that accepts a string, and logs the string content to a log file.

```
private static void LogEvent(string sEvent)
{
        sEvent = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") + "|" + sEvent;

        Console.WriteLine(sEvent);

        try
        {
            using (StreamWriter oStreamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter("MyService_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".log", true))
            {
                oStreamWriter.WriteLine(sEvent);
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }
}
```

When the program calling the function is manually run from the command line or by double clicking executable, the log file is either created or appended to.

The problem I have is I've set this program to be called from a task scheduler every 10 minutes, and for some reason the code is executing correctly, except the program is not creating or appending to the log file.

The scheduled task is calling the program using the same user permissions as when I manually ran the program.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it.

Comment: If you didn't hide the exception with an empty catch clause, you might have a better idea on how to fix it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're currently trying to write to the process's current working directory - which may well be something like `C:\Windows\System32` when it's executed by the task scheduler. You're not going to be able to write there.

Specify an absolute filename and I think you'll be fine. It's not clear where you *do* want to write to, but you should think about that carefully - ideally you should separate your executable files from the data that it generates. Consider using [`Environment.GetFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in conjunction with a suitable [`SpecialFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) member (e.g. `ApplicationData`.)

Note that using [`File.AppendAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendalltext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would make the code simpler, mind you.

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem.  I noticed that I was able to get the applications initial path using Application.StartupPath

Answer (score 2):

The answer by [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21309202/streamwriter-not-writing-to-file-when-called-from-task-scheduler-c-sharp/21309339#21309339) is right that the problem is with working directory permission and you should use [SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to write logs but I will like to add one more point,
Never have empty `catch` blocks like you did `catch { }` for me this `catch` statements sometime hides so many unknown problems.

I think they are something like teaser which says,

```
catch
{
    // WHO CARES
}
```

Never hide this sort of exceptions under the carpet, take some action or inform the end user or flag somewhere what has happened. This will help the developer in later stages.

Comment: A very least, exceptions that you want to _go away_ should be logged in `Trace` or other logging mechenism so you can see them if there is a big problem.